# Join Powershell Datatables

Tags: powershell, datatables

There are 2 Datatables $dt_1 and $dt_2.

$dt_1

| Facility | Customer | Contract |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | C1 |
| B | 234 | C2 |
| C | 567 | C3 |

$dt_2

| Facility | Customer | Contract | Material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | C1 | M1 |
| B | 234 | C2 | M1 |
| A | 123 | C1 | M2 |
| C | 567 | C3 | M2 |
| C | 567 | C3 | M4 |

I would like to output one row from each of the two datasets per Facility, Customer, Contract from $dt_1 with all the materials from $dt_2.

| Facility | Customer | Contract | Material - 1 | Material - 2 | Material - 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | C1 | M1 | M2 |  |
| B | 234 | C2 | M1 |  |  |
| C | 567 | C3 | M1 | M4 |  |

At the end I would like to write each row from the table to a CSV. I don't know what is the best access to the end result and am stuck here with the datatables which I can't join like in SQL.

I tried to play around with the merge command:

```
$merged = $dt_1 | ForEach-Object {
$dt1Row = $_
$dt2Rows = $dt_2 | Where-Object { $_.Facility -eq $dt1Row.Facility -and $_.Customer -eq $dt1Row.Customer -and $_.Contract -eq $dt1Row.Contract }
$dt1Row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Materials" -Value ($dt2Rows | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Material)
}

# Pivot the data to create the desired output format
$finalResult = $merged | ForEach-Object {
$entry = $_
$entry | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Material - 1" -Value ($entry.Materials[0])
$entry | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Material - 2" -Value ($entry.Materials[1])
$entry | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Material - 3" -Value ($entry.Materials[2])
}
```

but $finalResult comes out empty.

I think I got it to work:

```
$merged = $dt_1 | ForEach-Object {
$dt1Row = $_
$dt2Rows = $dt_2 | Where-Object { $_.Facility -eq $dt1Row.Facility -and $_.Customer -eq $dt1Row.Customer -and $_.Contract -eq $dt1Row.Contract }

$resultObject = $dt1Row | Select-Object Facility, Customer, Contract
$materialCount = 1

foreach ($material in $dt2Rows | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Material) {
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ("Material - $materialCount") -Value $material
    $materialCount++
}

$resultObject
```

}

Comment: Do you need table 1? Will it include things that are not on table 2? Will table 2 have things that should be excluded because they are not on table 1? This seems like something that could be accomplished with `$dt_2|group Facility,Customer,Contract|ForEach{build an object}` kind of code

Comment: Table 1 is needed because there's more in this table

Comment: Please excuse the circumstances I have changed the contract for Facility C.